# QGIS has duplicated SVG groups in Styling menu

Tags: qgis, style, svg

I'm running QGIS 2.14.8 (latest corporate user version) and SVG groups in the styling menu are duplicated 8 times. I searched for a bug entry but didn't find anything so I thought I'd post here.

Any idea how to clean the duplicates out of the menu?

I checked the instal path and SVG directory only has each folder once.

[image: duplicated SVG groups]

Comment: the current LTE Version is 2.14.15. So I would advise you to upgrade to this version and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: `Settings | Options` and select tab `System` will show you SVG paths. You can remove (clear) all displayed paths. It will reduce the duplicated trees. (These svg paths will be re-created when you close & reopen QGIS and continues doubling-up, though...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kazuhito for the answer:

Settings>Options and select tab System will show you SVG paths. You can remove (clear) all displayed paths. It will reduce the duplicated trees. (These svg paths will be re-created when you close & reopen QGIS and continues doubling-up, though...)

Nice to know how to add SVG path too! Thank you